# How do I calculate intersection between more than two HashSets?

Tags: java, intersection, hashset, retain

Considering the code below and the fact that the 4 `HashSet`s are populated elsewhere.

My aim is to contain all element(s) that are common in all 4 HashSets.

My question is that first of all, am I doing it right? Secondly, if I'm doing it right, is there a better way to do it? If not, then what solution do I have for this problem?

```
static Set<String> one=new HashSet<>();
static Set<String> two=new HashSet<>();
static Set<String> three=new HashSet<>();
static Set<String> four=new HashSet<>();

private static void createIntersectionQrels() {
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<String> interQrels = new HashSet<>();

    temp.addAll(one);
    one.retainAll(two);
    interQrels.addAll(one);
    one.addAll(temp);
    one.retainAll(three);
    interQrels.addAll(one);
    one.addAll(temp);
    one.retainAll(four);
    interQrels.addAll(one);
    one.addAll(temp);

    interQrels.retainAll(two);
    interQrels.retainAll(three);
    interQrels.retainAll(four);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can simply can call `retainAll()` on the first set, using the second, third, and fourth sets as parameters:

```
private static Set<String> getIntersectionSet() {
    // create a deep copy of one (in case you don't wish to modify it)
    Set<String> interQrels = new HashSet<>(one);

    interQrels.retainAll(two);     // intersection with two (and one)
    interQrels.retainAll(three);   // intersection with three (and two, one)
    interQrels.retainAll(four);    // intersection four (and three, two, one)

    return interQrels;
}
```

Comment: So I am just doing over-reacting to populate the first set every time i use  `retainAll()`? I just worried that if some info gets missed.

Comment: If an element really be common to all four sets, then you don't need to keep adding it (think about that for a moment).

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit new to Java 8, but this seems pretty readable:

```
    Set<String> intersection = one.stream()
                                  .filter(two::contains)
                                  .filter(three::contains)
                                  .filter(four::contains)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Here's a quick Junit test to try out:

```
@Test
public void testIntersectionBetweenSets() {
    Collection<String> one = new HashSet<>(4);
    one.add("Larry");
    one.add("Mark");
    one.add("Henry");
    one.add("Andrew");
    Set<String> two = new HashSet<>(2);
    two.add("Mark");
    two.add("Andrew");
    Set<String> three = new HashSet<>(3);
    three.add("Mark");
    three.add("Mary");
    three.add("Andrew");
    Set<String> four = new HashSet<>(3);
    four.add("Mark");
    four.add("John");
    four.add("Andrew");

    Set<String> intersection = one.stream()
            .filter(two::contains)
            .filter(three::contains)
            .filter(four::contains)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    Collection<String> expected = new HashSet<>(2);
    expected.add("Andrew");
    expected.add("Mark");
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, intersection);
}
```

Comment: Nice - should of though about streams ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

I would think the best way to handle this is with Groovy. I know you didn't ask for groovy, but anytime I can convert all that code into one line, it's hard to resist.

```
println one.intersect(two).intersect(three).intersect(four)
```